# Is there a way to remove a deleted file from my backup set without first restoring it?

Tags: backup, crashplan, crashplan-central

I've got a directory in my `/home/<user>/` folder that holds log dumps.

A couple of days ago I decided to do some housecleaning and deleted the logs.  Just now, I realized that Crashplan was backing them up (exactly like it's supposed to).

They'll get deleted in a year anyway but I was wondering if there's a way to force Crashplan to delete them sooner.  The only thing I could think of would be to restore them from backup and then deselect them from the backup set...which I'd rather not do because they're fairly large (which is why I deleted them in the first place).

**Is there any other way to force Crashplan to remove an already-deleted file from a remote backup set?**

Answer (score 5):

1. Under Settings enable backup sets.
2. Create a set for this folder and one for everything else you backup.
   For example:  1. Everything excepts logs
             2. Logs (/home/user/)

**Each backup set has independent settings!!**
3. Under Settings -> Backup -> Frequencies and versions
You can set the first one to a year.
Set the Logs for whatever you want.

When you want to delete logs move the slider down to every day.
Wait 24 or 48 hours.
Move the slider back to previous setting.

Comment: According to Crashplan the backup set with greatest priority will override the settings for the other backup sets. So even if you set the slider down to every day, it would not work. It would still prune files only after a year or whatever the original backup set used. The exception is if a backup set uses as different destination. Then the interval can be different. http://support.code42.com/CrashPlan/Latest/Configuring/Creating_Backup_Sets#Frequency_And_Version_Settings